# Pull Request Statuses - Added custom properties to a status aren't getting persisted by TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

We are operating a TFS 2018 Update 2 in our enviroment.

We are sending the example json found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20statuses/create?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) to our server and it is getting accepted successfully:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "sampleId": 7,
    "customInfo": "Custom status information",
    "startedDateTime": {
      "$type": "System.DateTime",
      "$value": "2017-09-19T14:50:26.7410146Z"
    },
    "weight": {
      "$type": "System.Double",
      "$value": 1.75
    },
    "bytes": {
      "$type": "System.Byte[]",
      "$value": "dGhpcyBpcyBzYW1wbGUgYmFzZTY0IGVuY29kZWQgc3RyaW5n"
    },
    "globalId": {
      "$type": "System.Guid",
      "$value": "1e788cb9-9d3d-4dc6-ac05-822092d17f90"
    }
  },
  "state": "succeeded",
  "description": "Sample status succeeded",
  "context": {
    "name": "sample-status-1",
    "genre": "vsts-samples"
  },
  "targetUrl": "http://fabrikam-fiber-inc.com/CI/builds/1"
}
```

But the response doesn't look like in the documentation. Instead it looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 6,
  "state": "succeeded",
  "description": "Sample status succeeded",
  "context": {
    "name": "sample-status-1",
    "genre": "vsts-samples"
  },
  "creationDate": "2019-12-11T16:14:05.0574648Z",
  "updatedDate": "2019-12-11T16:14:05.0574648Z",
  "createdBy": {
    "displayName": "...",
    "url": "https://.../_apis/Identities/0b85e078-130d-4cb8-a450-17c5c7efccec",
    "_links": {
      "avatar": {
        "href": "https://.../_api/_common/identityImage?id=0b85e078-130d-4cb8-a450-17c5c7efccec"
      }
    },
    "id": "0b85e078-130d-4cb8-a450-17c5c7efccec",
    "uniqueName": "...",
    "imageUrl": "https://.../_api/_common/identityImage?id=0b85e078-130d-4cb8-a450-17c5c7efccec"
  },
  "targetUrl": "http://fabrikam-fiber-inc.com/CI/builds/1",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://.../_apis/git/repositories/35fe73eb-7af1-4bba-bf04-545611fcac1d/pullRequests/58/statuses/6"
    },
    "repository": {
      "href": "https://.../_apis/git/repositories/35fe73eb-7af1-4bba-bf04-545611fcac1d"
    }
  }
}
```

The properties are gone. What could be wrong?
Could it be a somehow completely missleading documentation?

Comment: Hi friend, I tested the rest api in TFS2018 Update3 and it works. What's the result if you use completed,active,draft Pull request? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Hi @LanceLi-MSFT , the result on an active pullrequest is in the question above. On a completed one I get the error message "The requested pull request status cannot be updated as it requires an active pull request" (which makes sense). I have no know, what a draft pull request is.

Comment: I mean when someone approve it and choose mark it as draft status. But it's not the main point we should check, cause if you're using a active Pull request ID, I'm sure all my test with same script works no matter in TFS rest api or Azure Devops api... I did the tests it using PostMan. Could you share some details about how you format the http request.(Replacing the personal info with xxx to protect personal info)

Comment: According to my co-worker, draft pr's are only available with the new Azure devops server. Are you 100% sure, there are no changes between update 2 and 3? About my http request: I did use Insomnia. The body looks exactly like what I showed you above. In my case I used NTLM authentication. The content type is set to application/json. The whole request can be found under:
https://pastebin.com/raw/zJGusdQ4

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm not certainly sure if update the tfs to update3 can fix this issue. I'm now trying to configure a new machine with tfs update2 to check if I can reproduce the issue, it may take some time. And if possible, could you create a new collection in your tfs and test it using free postman? I want to check if it makes some difference using postman to do the test. Ps: I'll test it with tfs u2 and reply here as soon as possible:)

Comment: How did your test go? :)

Comment: Hi friend, sorry for the delay. What's your specific version of your TFS2018 U2? For me, i test the api in newest TFS2018 Update2 with Version 16.131.27701.1, and it works well. I can't reproduce same issue in my machine so far... If your machine is not latest 16.131.27701.1, trying updating it. Let me know if there's any update :)

Comment: And, to answer `Are you 100% sure, there are no changes between update 2 and 3?`, I'm sure it should have some changes between U2 and U3. But apparently the changes are not in rest api(at least this one), I just do several tests with TFS2018 U2+new collection and the api works as expected...

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT We decided to upgrade to the latest Azure Devops server during christmas holidays.  It's working right now, and we're using the exact same code (except increasing the api version string to 5.1-preview). So it is somehow resolved, although nobody knows now, what was going wrong with 2018 U3.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot your issue, please check the following items:

1. Check whether the `Status` updated on the pull request after running the `POST` request.

[image]

2. Press F12 in your browser, and send the `POST` request to check the `statuses` to see whether you can get `properties` in the response body.

[image]

3. Check your TFS edition by going to `Administration Console -- Application Tier`, or checking the `About` on the web portal. The issue can not be reproduced in TFS 2018.2 on our side.

[image]